# Special Price From Date attribute not showing

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, adobe-commerce

On the product edit page, if I click on the Advanced pricing link, the modal/slide-over panel comes in to show additional (editable) details.  However... the `special_from_date` and `special_to_date` are not visible.

I can create new attributes, and add them to the set, and they appear, but I cannot get these two items to show up.  I'm sure it's something stupidly simple that is not configured properly somewhere.

I should note that when I created a new test attribute (that does show) I compared it with the settings for these two attrs that are not.  Also, I've ran a SWAT report and looked for any potential patches that are may be missing that could be causing these issues.

Version: Adobe Commerce / Magento Cloud 2.4.2-p2

I've submitted a support ticket to Adobe... but we all know how speedy/helpful they can be at times.

Thoughts/comments?
Many thanks in advance :-)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create **di.xml** in your module. For example, **app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="attributesToEliminate" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="news_from_date" xsi:type="string">news_from_date</item>
            <item name="news_to_date" xsi:type="string">news_to_date</item>
            <item name="custom_design_from" xsi:type="string">custom_design_from</item>
            <item name="custom_design_to" xsi:type="string">custom_design_to</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Cache flush or run upgrade commands based on your mode of development. Let me know if it doesn't work, would be glad to help you further. Thanks

Comment: I've read that somewhere else as well... but unfortunately, this is not a custom module that we created.  I believe this is a native/built-in function.  I could be wrong as I'm still fairly new to M2, but all indications point to that.

I learned yesterday that these date fields only appear when/if someone uses the "Schedule New Update" at the top of any product page.  I had assumed that since there was data in the database, they would still appear.  Apparently not?!?  Also, this sale price data (price and dates) is being pumped in from NetSuite, so I have to deal with that issue as well.

Comment: In 2.4 as they have added scheduler functionality, so they have removed the dates field on purpose and yes you’re correct it’s native. In order to get the date fields back you need to create custom module and do the modifications as given in the answer. @Drew

Answer (score 0):

I heard back from Adobe support again finally after a week there and prior to posting here.

This was their response:

> *Hello Drew,*
>
> *Please note using **special_from_date** and **special_to_date** attributes to schedule special prices is a feature supported only in Magento Open Source, hence not displaying those attributes under the product edit page is the expected behavior in Adobe Commerce installations. The Adobe Commerce Scheduled Update feature overrides the Open Source price scheduling functionality.*
>
> *Please refer to the provided documentation which compares the special price scheduling in Magento Open Source and Adobe Commerce.*
>
> *Documentation: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/catalog/products/pricing/product-price-special.html*

So there's my answer I guess... :-/